# $\prod \cos(x2^{-k})$

Tags: calculus

Find 
$$
\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(x2^{-k}).
$$

Of course the first attempt is following:
$
\ln \prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(x2^{-k}) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\cos(x2^{-k}),
$
but it seems useless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have (for $x2^{-k}\not\equiv0\mod\pi$):

$$\cos\left(x2^{-k}\right)=\frac12\frac{\sin\left(x2^{-k+1}\right)}{\sin\left(x2^{-k}\right)}$$
so by telescoping

$$\prod_{k=1}^n \cos\left(x2^{-k}\right)=2^{-n}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\sin\left(x2^{-n}\right)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}$$